# Is there any way to restore an older version of a .Rnw file that's been overwritten?

Tags: rstudio, sweave

Shot in the dark here, but by accident I recently saved over an important .Rnw file in RStudio that contained months' worth of work. The new version I saved is missing pretty much everything. It would have been easier had I deleted the file altogether, rather than save over it. Unfortunately I wasn't pushing this file to GitHub, nor was it backed up on an external hard drive. It was saved on iCloud, but the Apple customer service rep said there's no way for them to recover an older version of the file. By any chance is there a way to access this from within RStudio (or my MacBook)? Any help you can provide would be *immensely* appreciated.

Comment: If the file has been overwritten, the only way to restore it would be to do so from a backup. *Overwritten* is destructive - once it happens, it's over.

Comment: Thanks. Thankfully, my MacBook's Time Machine was able to catch it. If I were using a different or older device, might have been a different story. Lesson learned: use version control.